# How to put a button into Quick Access Toolbar in MS Word 2010 with a macro (VBA)?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I import bsa file as module. And macro run properly. I need to set up these macros buttons in to Quick Access Toolbar (QAT). I do it manually from standart way as well. But i want to make this automatically with macro (VBA). How these macros assigned to the buttons and buttons set up on the QAT by VBA inside macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched a lot, and the only way I was able to find was [using Office Fluent User Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687747.aspx).

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687747.aspx) that walks you through doing it. The example is Excel's QAT, but since all Office Products share the same Type Library, you should be able to adapt it for MS Word 2010.